# How to draw a triangle using Path in Android?

Tags: c#, android, path

I need to draw a triangle as similar to attached below image using Path in Android. Can you please the valuable suggestion on this?

I have tried with following code snippet. Correct me if am wrong in below code snippet.

```
        Android.Graphics.Point a = new Android.Graphics.Point(0, 0);
        Android.Graphics.Point b = new Android.Graphics.Point(0, 100);
        Android.Graphics.Point c = new Android.Graphics.Point(87, 100);

        _path = new Path();
        _path.Reset();
        _path.LineTo(b.X, b.Y);
        _path.LineTo(c.X, c.Y);
        _path.LineTo(a.X, a.Y);
        _path.Close();
```

***Expected output:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just the coordinates are not right.

Try this

```
 Path _path = new Path();
    _path.reset();
    _path.moveTo(0,100);
    _path.lineTo(87, 100);
    _path.lineTo(87, 0);
    _path.close();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawPath(_path, paint);
```

Comment: @Parthiban are you drawing this path on a custom view?

Comment: Yes, By overriding the Xamarin Boxview